# Should I be able to see who accepted/rejected a suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I was clicking through my suggested edits queue again today and I accidentally discovered a way to see which users approved an edit and which rejected it.  Since most of the voting on things on SO is private, this struck me as odd.

Should I be able to access this information?  (I'm a 20k user on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Nope, that information has always been public. You get to see *all* suggested edit decisions if you have enough rep, by looking at http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Very interesting.  Is there any easy way to go back through and look at my reviews so I can compare how I vote to how others voted on the same reviews?

Comment: Good point.  I would be interested to see a rationale for which votes are public and which are secret.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to see this information. It's not intended to be private.

With enough reputation (not sure how much) you can see [recent suggested edit decisions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history) too.

You can see your own suggested edit votes in your 'activity' tab, filter on 'reviews'. That is a list of all review decisions, including the Close, Reopen, Late Answers, First Posts, and Suggested Edits, but cannot be filtered further.

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping for a `hacker` badge ;-)

Comment: Pretty sure the rep requirement is 2k.  I'm pretty sure it's not any more than that at least, because as soon as you can *use* the review queues you can see what other reviewers have done.

Comment: @Servy: Currently, at Programmers.SE I have 1.5k reputation, which means I can review first posts and late answers. I can only see *my own* reviews on the history tab..